# Can you hide the overflow of a CALayer?

Tags: objective-c

I'm a front-end developer new to objective-c. I'm working with a CALayer and was wondering if there is a way hide the overflow of a CALayer. Similar to overflow: hidden in CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`myView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;`